# CA2100: Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities

Tags: c#, mysql

Hey can someone help me with this code?
(visual studio give me a warning ca2100 and i dont know how to do this, and the solution on google i dont become them to work xD)

Thanks

```
private void Updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String selected = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(selected);
        Update(id, Kundennametxt.Text, Gamecbb.Text, Bezahlungcbb.Text,Bezahltcbb.Text, Erledigtcbb.Text, PayPalEmailtxt.Text,ACCEmailtxt.Text, ACCPWtxt.Text);
    }

    private void Update(int id, string Kundenname, string Game, string Bezahlung, string Bezahlt, string Erledigt, string PayPalEmail, 
        string ACCEmail, string ACCPW)
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE kunden SET Kundenname='" + Kundenname + "',Game='" + Game + "',Bezahlung='" + Bezahlung + 
            "',Bezahlt='" + Bezahlt + "',Erledigt='" + Erledigt + "',PayPalEmail='" + PayPalEmail +
            "',ACCEmail='" + ACCEmail + "',ACCPW='" + ACCPW + "' WHERE ID=" + id + "";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            {
                UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            };
            adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql;
            if (adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                ClearTxts();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated");
            }
            con.Close();
            Retrieve();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure )) This code is vulnerable to SQL injection: you pass strings (Kundenname, Game, etc) from potentially untrusted source directly to your query. Please read more about sql injections.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: hey thanks you for your answer but my english is not so good xD
i also have a add code for mysql and there its work but i dont get it with update to work xD

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting the values directly in the command like you currently do 
try like this

```
string sql= "UPDATE Kunden "+
" SET value1='?value1' WHERE ID=1";
try
{
  con.Open();
  cmd=new MySqlCommand(sql,con);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("value1",value1.Text));
  //and for every parameter you need like Game,Bezahlt,Kundenname add a new
  //cmd.Paramaters.Add(new MySqlParameter("paramName",paramValue));
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```